# Make seconds optional in LocalTimeConverter

Tags: asp.net-core, nodatime

By default it's mandatory to have seconds set in json request.

```
'time': '14:30' -> not valid and throws an exception
'time': '14:30:15' -> valid
```

I tried to create custom TypeConverter and register it via attribute

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(LocalTime), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(LocalTimeConverter)));
```

But custom converter is never called for POST request although for GET it does work.

Comment: Why not always have the seconds default to 00?

Comment: That's actually what i wanna have. I can't control what client sends to API. By default if seconds are not set it will throw an exception. Therefore i'm looking for a way to make seconds optional. Custom TypeConvert only seems to work for query parameters in GET requests

Comment: I've never used `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes` - are you able to get that working for other types? Is this actually specific to Noda Time in any way? (Where is that code being called?)

Comment: Yes it works but only for query parameters in GET requests. Also if i create my custom type which i can actually annotate with attribute without using TypeDescriptor then it works fine for POST and GET requests. This code is called in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method

Comment: @Ozonni - what he's getting at is whether this fails for _all_ POST requests (which your response seems to indicate is the case).  If so, this isn't a NodaTime problem, but a framework one.

Comment: @clockwork-muse - I'm not saying that it's NodaTime issue. I just wanna find a right way to change default behavior. There is always an option to write custom Json deserializer for LocalTime type but it looks like over-engineering. BTW i also use NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet which does all JSON serialization. So i would assume there should be a way to configure it there but i didn't find anything in documentation.

Comment: It sounds like there are two separate issues though: 1) Getting a custom converter working for POST as well as GET requests. 2) Applying the solution to point 1 with Noda Time. The set of people best placed to answer those two questions will probably be quite different, so I suggest you change the question to only focus on *one* of them (presumably the first one). You can ask a separate question for the other point...